# Simplify $\frac{1}{1-z}$, given $z = \cos \vartheta+ i\sin \vartheta$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm stuck on this question and was hoping for a hint:

Given: $z = \cos(\vartheta) + i\sin(\vartheta),$ show: $$\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\cot\left({\frac{\vartheta}{2}}\right)}{2}$$

I tried half angle and $\tan$ trig identity, but got nowhere!

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what _nowhere_ means? 

Comment: Means nowhere 

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are supposed to include every attempt. Why is no answer accepted?

Comment: Apologies @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya I have now accepted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note,

$$\frac{1}{1-z}= \frac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}}
= \frac{e^{-i\frac{\theta}2}}{e^{-i\frac{\theta}2}-e^{i\frac{\theta}2}} 
=\frac i2 \frac{\cos\frac{\theta}2-i \sin\frac{\theta}2 }{\sin\frac{\theta}2} =\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i}{2} \cot{\frac{\theta}{2}} $$

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks Quanto. No idea why I didn't spot this. Much better than faffing around with sines and cosines!

Comment: @Noobcoder - you’re welcome

Comment: btw, I noticed you edited $\theta$ to $\vartheta$. What's the difference? Do they mean different things?

Comment: @Noobcoder - not much, just a symbol

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-z} & = \frac{1}{1-\cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2\sin^{2}(\theta/2) - 2i\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2\sin(\theta/2)}\frac{1}{\sin(\theta/2) - i\cos(\theta/2)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\times\csc(\theta/2)\times(\sin(\theta/2) + i\cos(\theta/2))\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\cot(\theta/2)}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: I don' t know what's going on these days, but consecutive downvotes keep happening...

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya I've noticed this pattern of downvotes as well, but with it seeming to mostly happen with answers to questions that are generally poor quality, if not a basic PSQ (Problem Statement Question), at least close to one, such as this post's question. My guess is that, in at least many of such situations, one or more members are trying to discourage answering such questions by downvoting the answers.

Comment: Just for clarification I don’t down vote. Don’t think I ever have.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{1-(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))}\\
\frac{1}{(1-\cos(\theta)) - i\sin(\theta)}=\\
\frac{1}{(1-\cos(\theta)) - i\sin(\theta)}\times \frac{(1-\cos(\theta)) + i\sin(\theta)}{(1-\cos(\theta)) + i\sin(\theta)}$$
Next step is simplifying.

Comment: I tried this way but couldn’t simplify it! Will try again tomorrow. Thanks